# iCloud two-factor authentication on OS X Yosemite

Tags: ios, macos, icloud, two-factor-authentication, two-step-authentication

I have 3 Apple devices, an iPhone and iPad both running iOS 11 and a MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite 10.10.

On the iOS devices I am getting alerts to enable two-factor authentication for my iCloud account.

Will enabling it restrict me from accessing my iCloud account on my MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in the Apple support document, [Availability of two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT205075):

> Two-factor authentication is available to iCloud users with at least one device that's using iOS 9 or OS X El Capitan or later.

Since your iOS devices are running iOS 11, you should be covered.

Comment: Thanks, Seeing as 2FA requires El Capitan (10.11) and im running Yosemite (10.10) what would happen to my iCloud on my macbook pro, if 2FA is enabled ?

Comment: Nothing will happen to the iCloud on your MacBook. The statement in the document mentions the minimum required OS versions on respective devices to **receive** the code. Since you are using iOS 11 with the same Apple ID as on your MacBook, you should be covered.